# How do I write a program to find A,B answer that AAB +BB =BAA in python?

Tags: python

topic:
If A and B are both integers from 1 to 9, try to find out those (A, B) values that can meet the following conditions: AAB+BB=BAA

What I write:

```
for A in range (1,10):
    for B in range(1,10):
        if                  #I have no idea...
           print(A,B)
```

Comment: How do you get from `B` to `BB`? By `* 11`. Want `BA`? `10 * B + A`.

Comment: A*100+A*10+B*10+2*B == B*100+A*10+A ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner : can be shorten as : 9*A = 8*B

Answer (score 1):

Well, start with the fact that `AAB` is equal to `A * 100 + A * 10 + B`.

Apply that to the others, work out the expressions, and test for equality.

---

For example<sup>(1)</sup>, to test if `ABBA + AB` is exactly seven greater than `BBBB`, you could use something like:

```py
abba = A * 1000 + B * 100 + B * 10 + A   # or A * 1001 + B * 110
ab   =                      A * 10 + B
bbbb = B * 1000 + B * 100 + B * 10 + B   # or B * 1111

if abba + ab == bbbb + 7:
    do_something()
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Hopefully close enough that you can work it out for your specific question, but not so close that you can just plagiarise :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from itertools import product

[(A,B,f'{A}{A}{B} + {B}{B} = {B}{A}{A}')
 for A,B in product(range(1,10), range(1,10))
 if A*100+A*10+B+B*10+B == B*100+A*10+A]
```

output: `[(8, 9, '889 + 99 = 988')]`

Using a classical loop:

```
for A in range(1,10):
    for B in range(1,10):
        if A*100+A*10+B+B*10+B == B*100+A*10+A:
            print(f'A={A}, B={B} -> {A}{A}{B} + {B}{B} = {B}{A}{A}')
```

output:

```
A=8, B=9 -> 889 + 99 = 988
```

Comment: You *can* but, if you can't explain it to the teacher, you're going to be in a ***lot*** of trouble, assuming this is classwork, which seems likely :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo It isn't mentioned that this is an assignment :p (It is likely one, but according to rules it should be explicitly mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You can really simplify this by just casting to strings and back to integers. Since this is a small enough *n* there won't be any performance concerns.

You could apply math by adding factors of `10` in the appropriate places but to me, this is the most obvious what's going on.

```
for A in range (1, 10):
    for B in range(1, 10):
        AAB = int(str(A) + str(A) + str(B))
        BB = int(str(B) + str(B))
        BAA = int(str(B) + str(A) + str(A))
        if AAB + BB == BAA:
             print(A, B)
```

Or with f-strings.

```
for A in range (1, 10):
    for B in range(1, 10):
        AAB = int(f'{A}{A}{B}')
        BB = int(f'{B}{B}')
        BAA = int(f'{B}{A}{A}')
        if AAB + BB == BAA:
             print(A, B)
```

Comment: Should be range 0,9

Comment: @PtitXav: you should read the question more closely :-) Digits are `1..9` inclusive.

Comment: Sorry, missed it

Comment: It might be nicer to use f-strings ;)

Comment: @mozway Yeah, I love f-strings and use them exclusively in all my professional work. :) I have noticed beginners shy away from them though, which is why I threw out the first option.

Comment: maybe they just don't know about it, as they are relatively recent I guess many tutorials don't use them, one more reason to spread the word ;)

Answer (score 0):

At first, lets simplify the expression.
`AAB + BB = BAA` == `100A + 10A + B + 10B + B = 100B + 10A + A` == `99A = 88B` == `9A = 8B`.

As you can see, we can already suggest the right answer (`A` should be the value of `B` multiplier and vise versa).

But if you really need to write some Python code, here you go:

```py
    for a in range(1, 10):
        for b in range(1, 10):
            if a * 9 == b * 8:
                print(f'A={a}, B={b}')
```

Output: `A=8, B=9`